# how to scrape the data with expandable tabs and subsequent POST requests (CORS problem)

Tags: python, web-scraping

There is a [website](https://econjobmarket.org/positions) which I need to scrape. It has a long list of available job positions, that are folded by default:

[image: folded positions]

Which unfold when a user clicks on it:

[image: Unfolded]

When a user unfolds it, the page sends a POST request to a website with a position id.

I tried to imitate this request (see code below), it *doesn't* fail (status==200) but doesn't return anything. I suspect that is because of CORS. Is there anyway to still collect the data?

```py
import requests

url = "https://econjobmarket.org/positions/recordClick"

payload = 'posid=7026'
headers = {
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': HERE_GOES_THE_TOKEN,
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  'Cookie': HERE_GOES_THE_COOKIE
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see additional requests sent to get expanded data. All data (both in folded and expanded states are already in page source)

[image]

```
response = requests.get('https://econjobmarket.org/positions').content
print("Post-Doc, Computational Marketing" in response)
True
```

Comment: Believe me it’s there. If you open the console in chrome and choose “Network” section you’ll post requests sent each time you expand it

Comment: It is there, but it is just for web analytics and doesn't return any data.

Comment: @PhilippChapkovski , yes , I see "recordClick" XHR-request, but I guess it used just for statistics (so that server will keep info about how much times user check each job description)

Answer (score 1):

The recordClick URL you are seeing is simply for recording the click for web analytics. As Parolla said, what you are looking for is already in the page source. Your best bet is to do an HTTP GET on the website and parse the html code with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the ability of the site to track you and potentially block your scraping if you drop the token and cookies from the request headers.

A quick test in curl shows the response is still complete without them.

```
curl -i -s -k -X $'GET' \
    -H $'Host: econjobmarket.org' -H $'Connection: close' -H $'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H $'DNT: 1' -H $'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H $'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.101 Safari/537.36' -H $'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H $'Sec-GPC: 1' -H $'Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site' -H $'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' -H $'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' -H $'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' -H $'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H $'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
    $'https://econjobmarket.org/positions'
```

J and Parolla are correct that the POST is just recording your actions on the website.